# Auto incremental field filled with filtered by other field value in QGIS Attribute Form

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-expression, unique-value, attribute-form

From a point geometry layer with two categories "A" and "B", when I enter new points, I first choose the category of the `"CATEG"` field with a listbox, and then I use the following expression in the form properties to add a value in `"ORDER"` field for introducing an autoincremental value depending on the value of `"CATEG"` field:

```
if(maximum("ORDER") is NULL, 1, maximum("ORDER") + 1)
```

Screenshot of the form:

[image]

Screenshots of the form properties:

[image]

[image]

At the moment this workflow is not what my project needs because I can't get the autoincremental value to take into account the value of the `"CATEG"` field.

My goal is:

- Enter a value and choose "A" or "B" in the `"CATEG"` field
- If it is the first point for "A" or "B", then the `"ORDER"` field should be filled with the value 1
- If it is the second point or later, then the `"ORDER"` field should be filled with the previous value +1

For example: if I enter a point with `"CATEG"=A` and the last value is 4, the `"ORDER"` field should be filled with the value 5. But if I choose `"CATEG"=B` and the last value is 2, the `"ORDER"` field should be filled with the value 3.

What expression could I use in the `"ORDER"` field form to make it work with this logic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the second parameter `group_by` as `"CATEG"` for the [`maximum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#maximum) function.

```
if(maximum("ORDER", "CATEG") is NULL, 1, maximum("ORDER", "CATEG") + 1)
```

[image]